# SailsJs: getting "304 not modified" page after deploy

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I'm trying to update my SailsJs application to fix the blank page which I'm getting on Heroku, but I'm getting the status 304 not modified from browser.

[image]

I think I did everything I need to fix the blank page on my app, but I don't know why the page is not updating on Heroku

My Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
```

I appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to fix anything. If you try to call the same url using  POSTMAN or different browser  you should get status 200.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to a policy instead and then just apply it to the specific pages/requests you want - if you do not want to set this for the entire application.

**/api/policies/nocache.js:**

```
    /**
     * Sets no-cache header in response.
     */
    module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
        sails.log.info("Applying disable cache policy");
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
        res.header('Expires', '-1');
        res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');  
        next();
    };
```

**Don't forget to include nocatche into config/policy.js**

```
'*': 'nocatche'
```